# restrict image upload in uploadify

Tags: php, html

I am using uploadify to upload images . Is there any way to restrict user to upload other than image with width:670px height:200px.
 here is my uploadify.php code

```
<?php
require_once("includes/connection.php");

$targetFolder = '/workbench/sudeepc/photogallery/uploads' ; 

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

 $query="INSERT INTO `photo` ( `id` , `path` , `uname` )
 VALUES (
 '','${targetFile}', 'testnn');";
 mysql_query($query,$connection);


    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you can restrict the actual upload - the file will have to be uploaded in order for your server side logic to test it's validity - file extension, dimensions, etc...

There is a built in PHP function to determine image sizes - 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
getimagesize()
```

> The getimagesize() function will determine the size of any given image
>   file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a
>   height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and
>   the correspondant HTTP content type.
>   ...
>   Returns an array with 7 elements.
>   Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the image.

After you have checked the file extension, you can call this function on the image and test it's dimensions against your requirements.

Here is an example output of the function -

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 84 // width
  [1] => 52 // height
  ... 
)
```